# Running Symfony plug-in tasks via command line SSH on shared hosting

Tags: command-line, symfony1, ssh

My usual hosting environment is a dedicated server, however for one project I am required to deploy Symfony onto a Linux shared hosting account.

The project itself works fine, however, when I SSH in to the server the command line does not work as expected.

For example, if I navigate to data/symfony/bin then type:

```
php symfony
```

this returns the list of symfony functions, but not the tasks associated to my plug-ins such as sfLucene.

**How do I make the CLI aware of the plug-ins, so that I can run tasks such as rebuilding my sfLucene index?**

Comment: Does the shared host have symfony installed globally on the php include_path? If it does, it may be getting in the way of your project.

Comment: How about copying data/symfony/bin/symfony to your project's root directory? I'm not sure I like the paths being used - check which symfony and which php commands are being used, or be explicit. Remember too, the CLI version of PHP may be quite different to Apache's SO version, and may use different php.ini files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I asked my hosts to improve my access so that my scripts would run.

I could then run the default symfony file in the root of the project directory:

```
php symfony lucene-rebuild
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialise the Symfony application instance at the top of the script you want to run, and stick the stuff you want to do in the script:

```
require_once('/var/www/domains/yourdomain.com/www/htdocs/config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php');
$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', 'prod', false);
sfContext::createInstance($configuration);
```

*(change to your own project path)*

That's what I use to run Cron jobs or just execute Symfony stuff via CLI.

Does that help?

Comment: This would solve the underlying problem of executing symfony from a cronjob or CLI, but the wider (and more elegant) solution of making the user-defined task available to the CLI remains.

Comment: @Raise: what I had in mind was to run the task from within that script, giving it access to everything it needs.

Comment: I understand and agree, as this would mimic the old batch/ script approach from symfony 1.0+, but the task should really be available to the CLI without your workaround.

Comment: @Raise... fair enough, I guess it's a bit of hassle to create scripts just to execute other scripts.